# How to user Android-Volley to set animated image until the image loads

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-volley

In android `volley`, I know there's an attribute called `mDefaultImageId` in the NetwrokImageView. But this only displays "Default" still images.

I need to show either an animated image or a progress bar.

I know I can accomplish this if I use `RequestQueue`, but still I need to take advantages of `ImageLoader`.

How to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own implementation of the `ImageListener` class and pass it when requesting the image.

Something along the lines of:

```
// code for displaying animation / progress wheel

sImageLoader.get(imageUrl, new ImageListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // handle errors
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
            // code to switch out placeholder animation 
            // progress wheel with received response
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is no working, because when you get this event the Progress bar for that view has been recycled and you will try to set some other progress bar.

Comment: It does work. I don't what you tried to do, but if a view gets recycled it points to a logical problem in your code.

Comment: it works only for one request. If you are using Volley for list view or grid view with recyclable views then it points to the last loaded view. If a view is recycled then the task is stopped as per Volley specs and no response comes to the listener ...

Comment: I don't understand your situation exactly. Even in a list view there should be no problem. If you'd like, post a separate question with a snippet of your code and more information and I'll take a look.

Comment: No need to understand my situation, mate :) If you want to set a Progress bar to an imageview while Volley is getting the image the answer you provided is not working. Because you are setting an ImageListener to a view that has been stopped. This may work in VolleySingleton, but have not tested it. If you set a Listener the way you did it will come for the last view, but it wont come for the previous views.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: https://github.com/vinaysshenoy/enhanced-volley
there is Animation added to Volley.

also you can use

```
NetworkImageView ivImage = (NetworkImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
ivImage.setImageUrl(key, mImageLoader);
ivImage.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.loading_text);
```

where for me drawable loading_text was image saying "Loading image..."

Comment: Instead of an image saying loading image, how to add an actual spinner?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using method to load image then ProgressBar as parameter to that method may help you to hide ProgressBar:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32666637/5045178